# Privilege viewer?

Tags: support, privileges

Is there a way to easily see what permissions you have, like you can see how much/many rep and badges you have?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges

Comment: Thank you, but why isn't there one in your personal profile where you can track your progress of your privileges, or if you lose them a way to see what you lost

Comment: That page is personalised in that it shows all your current privileges with a green tick.

Comment: yes, but why isn't it on the page that you see your badges on?

Comment: @DanHolli It used to be linked there; the changes to the system to move things into the Help Center buried it a little, so it's harder to find

Comment: @ThomasWard, thanks I had just found it

Comment: @DanHolli It's in your profile under "Edit Profile & Settings". Bottom link in the column on the left. No idea why they put it in the settings tab...